# problem with login control

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem with login control.I have three pages called login,secret and register.I secured my secret page by using login control and if i request my secret page it redirect me to the login page that is fine to me.but problem is that if from here i click on the regiser link it does not direct to the register page untill i fill any correct enrty.if i fill correct login/password it direct me to the secret page.now if i come back  to the login page and now click the register link it dirct me to the register page.thts fine now.

i have used createtext and createtexturl property of login control.please help me in this regard...

I have the follwing code in web config file.

```
<roleManager enabled="true"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

and following in the source file......

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
  DestinationPageUrl="~/Secret.aspx" 
  CreateUserText="New User Register" 
  CreateUserUrl="~/register.aspx" 
  FailureText="You are not registered.....try agian.." />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have not only "secured" your secret page, but also the register page.

The code you have entered in your question is not visible (you should select the code and click the button with the 0 and 1's), but try adding something like this to the configuration section of your web.config.

```
<location path="register.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Have you definitely specified the correct path? Janzi's answer looks like the correct one to me

Answer (score 0):

Amit,

To check whether the issue is with your authorization setup, you might like to temporarily try this:

```
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

If everything works after this check that `<location path="register.aspx">` is correct- do you have it in a subfolder?

Comment: using this iit workin but now i can dircly open the secret page.that i dont want.

Comment: OK so that confirms that you have an authorization issue- you now must ensure that you configure the location path value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, now that we can see the code, we have a better chance of helping you ;)

You haven't said as much, but I'm assuming that you have all three files - login, register and secret in the same folder?

If so, what you're saying with this:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Is "Deny all anonymous users access to these pages" - and this is overriding the location "allow all users" option suggested by Janzi.

Try some of the following:

```
//Folder structure
web.config - Root Web.config
Login.aspx - login page
Register.aspx - registration page
/Secret - Folder called "Secret"
/web.config - web.config in "Secret"
/Secret.aspx - secret pages
```

The web.config in the /Secret folder should just contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

While your root web.config defines your membership provider, defines the settings for forms auth, etc.

Alterntatively, you can remove the web.config in /Secret and just use a location element in the root web.config:

```
<location path="Secret">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```